# Display element dynamically on HttpClient requests

Tags: aurelia

I want to display a loader for every fetch done by my app, preventing the user from submiting the same request multiple times. For this I changed the HttpClient configuration to intercept the requests and responses during configuration in main.ts

---

```
    let httpClient = new HttpClient();

    httpClient.configure(config => {
       config.withInterceptor({
            request(request) {
                // displayLoader();
                return request;
            },
            response(response) {
                // hideLoader();
                return response;
            },
        });
    });​
```

If it was plain js I would do something like document.body.appendChild... but Aurelia doens't let me do that.

Is there a way to display a custom view dynamically, without changing the route or having to insert a new loading view on every component that is doing a request?

Also if you have a better approach for this problem I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I mean, Aurelia doesn't stop you from using `document.appendChild`, it just strongly discourages you from using it.

Comment: yeah I felt bad for accessing the DOM directly, I was just tesing some options, but the appendChild had a weird behavior in my implementation. I'm sticking with the best practices, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an option that might work for you. In your `main.js`, have something that looks like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  const container = aurelia.container;

  const httpClient = container.get(HttpClient);
  const ea = container.get(EventAggregator);

  httpClient.configure(config => {
    config.withInterceptor({
      request(request) {
        ea.publish('http-request', request);
        return request;
      },
      response(response) {
        ea.publish('http-response', response);
        return response;
      }
    });
  });

  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .singleton(HttpClient, httpClient);


  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

Then, in `app.js` or whatever you are using for your app's root page. Have something like this:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class App {
  displayLoader = false;
  constructor(ea) {
    this.ea = ea;

    ea.subscribe('http-request', () => this.displayLoader = true);
    ea.subscribe('http-response', () => this.displayLoader = false );
  }
...
```

Then simply use databinding w/`if.bind="displayLoader"` or `show.bind="displayLoader"` in `app.html`.

Comment: Nice approach, It's working like a charm. Thank you.